# How to most efficiently find out if a record has child records?

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-tuning

I am writing a query that returns a single record from the `parent` table. I would like to also return in this query if it has any children. This is a one to many relationship.

```
parent:
 -parent_id
 -name

child:
-child_id
-name
-parent_id
```

My first instinct is to write the following query:

```
select name, (select count(child_id) from child c  where c.parent_id=p.parent_id) children
     from parent p
     where name like 'some name'
```

But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this, since I don't actually care about the count, just whether or not it has children. Any pointers?

Comment: Exactly. Use `exists` instead of counting all the children. I often liken this concept to someone asking how many people are in a room, versus asking whether or not the room is occupied. While knowing that there are 437 people in a room is nice, it's overkill if you're just looking for an empty room to use for a meeting...

Comment: @Colin'tHart good simile!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't forget that Postgres has a boolean datatype. The following is the most succinct way to express the query:

```
select
  parent_id,
  name,
  exists (select from child where parent_id = p.parent_id) as has_children
from parent p;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=86748ba18ba8c0f31f1b77a74230f67b

Comment: Colin, it seems I did a poor job with my example. Let's say I am *not* selecting a specific parent, but rather many, will that sub query cause poor performance, or will it only run on  parent records whose where clause matches? see updated question above

Comment: It’s fine. It will only perform the exists check for parents matching the where clause.

Answer (score 11):

## Methods

### Aggregate Method

The popular way we'll call it the **aggregate method**. *Note `bool_or(child_id IS NOT NULL)` also works but was not any faster.*

```
SELECT parent_id, count(*)>1 AS has_children
FROM parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN children
  USING (parent_id)
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

### `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` with limit

But you may also try this, with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL()` like this..

```
SELECT parent_id, has_children
FROM parent AS p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT true
  FROM children AS c
  WHERE c.parent_id = p.parent_id
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) AS t(has_children)
  ON (true);
```

### `EXISTS`

Just FYI, you can use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` with `EXISTS` too (which is I believe how it's planned). We'll call it the **EXISTS method**.

```
SELECT parent_id, has_children
FROM parent AS p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT 
    FROM children AS c
    WHERE c.parent_id = p.parent_id
  )
) AS t(has_children);
```

Which is the same as,

```
SELECT parent_id, EXISTS(
    SELECT 
    FROM children AS c
    WHERE c.parent_id = p.parent_id
) AS has_children
FROM parent AS p;
```

## Benchmarks

### Sample dataset

1000000 children, 2500 parents. Our sims get it done.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  parent_id int PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO parent
  SELECT x
  FROM generate_series(1,1e4,4) AS gs(x);
CREATE TABLE children (
  child_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int REFERENCES parent
);
INSERT INTO children
  SELECT x, 1 + (x::int%1e4)::int/4*4
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS gs(x);

VACUUM FULL ANALYZE children;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE parent;
```

### Results (pt1)

- Aggregate method: 450ms,
- `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )`: 850ms
- **EXISTS** method: 850ms

### Results (adding an index and running again)

Now let's add an index

```
CREATE INDEX ON children (parent_id);
ANALYZE children;
```

Now the timing profile is **totally different**,

- Aggregate method: 450ms,
- `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )`: 30ms
- **EXISTS** method: 30ms

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do in SQL server (I don't have postgresql- I'm guessing it would be similiar)

```
SELECT p.parent_id,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Child c WHERE c.ParentId=p.ParentId)
                THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
                END as has_child,
FROM Parent p
--WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Child c WHERE c.ParentId=p.ParentId)
```

Answer (score -3):

As long as there is index on parent_id column of child table your query should be good.

Comment: There's no need to count all the children, so there's definitely room for performance improvement.